# Geth Send Transaction

Tags: go-ethereum

I am having serious issues with mist, is it possible to open geth in command line (mac) and send a. erc20 token via it?

for example

send _____ from _____ to _____ gas = ______

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it manually with web3 and the `sendTransaction()` function. You will probably need to call the `transferFrom()` function of the smart contract of the token.

You will need:

- the address of the token contract
- the abi of the token contract
- to sign the transaction with the private key of the wallet that bought the token

See here for the ERC20 token standard:
https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Finding the source code of your token might also help.